# Scp command to copy the particular folder without recursively

Tags: bash, shell, unix, jenkins

I am migrating the jobs from one server to another server of jenkins.  Please find the  below job structure

```
 job1                   job2         job3         
 config.xml             config.xml    config.xml
 buildnumber            buildnumber   buildnumber
 last build             last build    last build
```

As the above mentioned job structure, we have lot of jobs. I need to copy only the job name and inside the config.xml of all the jobs to the corresponding jobs in the another server. Can anyone help to copy from one server to another unix server(centos). If i use scp -r , it copies all the subfolders, i need to copy only the job name and the config.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Your can use `rsync`

```
rsync -av --include=job[123]/config.xml --exclude=job[123]/* -e ssh job[123] remote-server:/your/disired/path/
```

or you can use `tar`

```
tar -cpvf - job[123]/config.xml | ssh remote-server "cd /your/desired/path/; tar -xpf -"
```

or if your `tar` supports `-C`

```
tar -cpvf - job[123]/config.xml | ssh remote-server tar -xpf - -C /your/desired/path/
```